# How do I create a terminal timer?

Tags: bash

How can I create a simple terminal timer? I'm not sure how to get my terminal to make sounds. Any advice?

What I tried:

```
tput bell
echo -e '\a'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
~/
❯ cat timer.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# $1 is the only argument to this function
# the user will input it as minutes

seconds=$(($1*60))

while test $seconds -gt 0
do
    # print each minute
    if test $(($seconds % 60)) -eq 0
    then
        echo $(($seconds/60))
    fi
    sleep 1
    seconds=$((seconds-1))
done

say -v Tessa "finished"


~/
❯ bash timer.sh 5
5
4
3
2
1

~/
❯
```

Comment: Why the loop and not just `sleep ${seconds}`?

Comment: Because the loop gives you a countdown.  Some interesting takes on how to do this are here https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/120548-60-second-timer-shell-script.html

Comment: Little improvement: `echo -n "$(($seconds/60)) "` to keep the output on the same line ;) note the `-n` and extra space after the digit is printed within quotations. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38021348/how-can-i-echo-out-things-without-a-newline